# How to get year 1952 up to the present year?

Tags: javascript

I am having a little bit of trouble of getting an array of objects with years from 1952 to the present year and here is the code that I have done below:

```
     var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

     var fullYears = [];

     years = {};

     for(var y = 1952; y < currentYear; y--)
     {
           years.value = y;

           fullYears.push(years);
     }
```

Comment: I'd question why you have an array for this. you could easily generate an object given an index on demand. `function getYearObj(index) {return {value: 1952+index};}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a fresh object each time:

```
for(var y = 1952; y < currentYear; y++)
    fullYears.push({ value: y });
```

Also you want `++` to increment up from 1952 to now.